# Indefinite integration giving expression in ArcTanh

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am using Mathematica version 12 and facing a problem which was not present in the previous version. I am performing indefinite integration $(x/((1-x^2)\sqrt{1+a^2 x^2+b^2 x^4}))$ and getting the answer in `ArcTanh`, but I want the answer in `Log`, taking real part of the solution.

I think Mathematica is assuming the solution to be both real and complex. I also tried using `Assuming`, but the solution remains same. `ComplexExpand` makes the expression complicated and `Simplify` is of not much use. I am giving the part of the code for clarity.

```
y[x_] = 
  Integrate[x/((1 - c^2 x^2) Sqrt[1 + a^2 x^2 + b^2 x^4]), x, 
    Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

Any help or comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `TrigToExp[ y[x] ] `

Comment: Your question is unclearly formulated. Applying TrigToExp to the result of the Integrate command, one obtains $$\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{a^2 \left(-\left(c^2 x^2+1\right)\right)-2 \left(b^2 x^2+c^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2 c^2+b^2+c^4} \sqrt{a^2 x^2+b^2 x^4+1}}\right)}{4 \sqrt{a^2 c^2+b^2+c^4}}-\frac{\log \left(\frac{a^2 \left(-\left(c^2 x^2+1\right)\right)-2 \left(b^2 x^2+c^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2 c^2+b^2+c^4} \sqrt{a^2 x^2+b^2 x^4+1}}+1\right)}{4 \sqrt{a^2 c^2+b^2+c^4}}. $$

Comment: `TrigToExp` still gives the answer assuming both complex and real solutions. I want `Log` assuming the solutions real only.

Comment: Wether the integral becomes real or complex depends on the parameters, especially `x`, you choose. It's up to you to choose appropriate parameters!

Comment: The log expressions obtained by `TrigToExp` can be passed to `Refine[...,Assumptions->...]` to indicate which values are assumed to be real.